# selenium cannot run on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```
package com.confirm;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;
  public class ConfirmDemo {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test
    public void ExampleForConfrim() throws InterruptedException {
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.get("file:///C:/confirm.html");
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@onClick='confirmFunction()']"));
     Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
     System.out.println(alert.getText());
     alert.dismiss();
     driver.close();
 }
}
```

This is my first selenium program. I type this code in eclipse and also add external jar files for selenium, when I run the eclipse says :

> The selection cannot be launch, and there are no recent launches.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has more to do with eclipse than it does with Selenium, check out [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380792/eclipse-error-the-selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launch).